# xPages - Pager onClick Event issue

Tags: events, onclick, xpages, pager

I'm trying to put an onClick event on a pager which is in a dataView. I want the onClick event to update a sessionScope variable. I've added the code and tested it, I can't get it to work. I made a test button and set it up with the same onClick event and the variable is updated correctly.

Right now, if I click the pager it works correctly and pages through the dataView. But, it doesn't update the sessionScope variable. Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
<xp:pager partialRefresh="true" id="pager8" xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
                            styleClass="mblFooterLeft">
     <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:isPagerDisplayed();
}]]></xp:this.rendered>

    <xp:pagerControl id="pagerControl2" type="Previous">

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                 refreshMode="partial" refreshId="testLabel">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:incPagerDisplay(); 
                     sessionScope.pagerDisplay++;}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>

    </xp:pagerControl>
</xp:pager>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure this is problem with your code. It seems that events do not fire (client or server) from `xp:pagerControl` ([reference link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=CE2B5241C13AD65E8525790B0065B20D)).

Answer (score 0):

While you're asking for an onClick event update to a *sessionScope*'d variable, it seems from your code that your end attempt is to save the page'd state the user is on, so they can navigate away/back and retain that from the *sessionScope* var. Assuming that's all you're trying to do with it, I recommend you check out and use the [*xe:pagerSaveState* control](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=pagerSaveState_Pager_Save_State_ddxl853&content=pdcontent).

Brad Balassaitis wrote [a blog post](http://xcellerant.net/2013/08/08/xpages-data-views-6-pager-save-state-control/) on using it with a Data View, which may assist you. Oliver Busse tweaked that implementation a bit and [demonstrates with his OSnippet](http://www.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=7B51A244886FC9D7C1257C4800122599); a massage to the SSJS call.

Here's [Oliver's snippet](http://www.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=7B51A244886FC9D7C1257C4800122599):

```
<xe:pagerSaveState id="pagerSaveState1" refreshId="theView" partialRefresh="true">
</xe:pagerSaveState>

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewStateBean.restoreState = true;}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Comment: @user3641366 Any luck trying out the pager save state control?